# Unique index with fluent api

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I got a table Person, Order and PersonOrder.

In the table PersonOrder i have a column PersonId and OrderId.
How can I create a `unique index` between these columns with `Fluent API`?

This was my try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonOrder>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.PersonId , l.OrderId});


[Table("PersonOrder")]
public class PersonOrder
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to think for a while to get what you *probably* mean. I think you mean that there are non-unique indexes on `PersonOrder.PersonId` and `PersonOrder.OrderId`.

But there *is* a unique index on the primary key `PersonOrder.PersonId + PersonOrder.OrderId`. And that's the only thing that should be unique. The index on the individual fields can never be unique. That would mean that the association is in fact not many-to-many, but one-to-many.

Or is that what you're after: to have a 1 (Person) to many (Orders) association? (With a unique `PersonOrder.OrderId`). In that case you might as well model the association as a regular 1 to many: `Person.Orders` and `Order.Person` (singular).

Comment: Hi, you're right, the association should be many-to-many. I gave person and order as an example of the real names of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

**what's wrong with that?** - that's the way for a many-to-many `composite index`...

I'll just post the full example how it's usually done / mapped for many to many with all columns (and typical navigation properties that you probably have already):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonOrder>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.PersonId, x.OrderId }); 

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonOrder>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Person)
    .WithMany(x => x.PersonOrders)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonOrder>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Order)
    .WithMany(x => x.PersonOrders)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Hi, i have already created the table (question updated with the code), but when i look into my database, i still see 'Nonunique' in the 'index' folder.

Comment: could you just post your migration script for the tables (or SQL generated - if you're using migrations you already have that readily). Also, to avoid repeating, **read what @GertArnold just posted**. **The key is unique, but that's a `composite key`**. Anyway, I'd need to see your SQL or scripts to be able to tell you more.

Comment: Hi, Gert was right. I was looking at it the wrong way. Thanks for your help!